# a flask web application that obtains two data from a user only accepts data in one field

Tags: python, forms, flask

I'm noob in Flask and Python.
It is my frstfsfs fsf fsfsfs

My goal is to create an web application.
There are 3 files in my application.
In the browswer there are 3 fields:

```
The sine2 of    ------------ equals
The cossine2 of ------------ equals
sin2(x) + co2(x)------------ equals
```

Only the field sine2 works showing the value.
Nothing else works.

The goal is:

```
Enter a value in sine2 and click on the equal. The result of sine2 is showed.
The value appears in the field cosine2 and sin2+cos2. After the cliking on equal the cossine2 is showed.

Then click on the square sine to show the value.
The same applies when the cosine value is entered first.
```

[visualizing in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08WpW.png)

controller.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from compute import *
from model import InputForm

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 


def index():
    form = InputForm(request.form)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        r = form.r.data
        s = sin2(r)
    else:
        s = None

    return render_template("view.html", form=form, s=s)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        d = form.r.data
        e = cos2(d)
    else:
        e = None

    return render_template("view.html", form=form, e=e)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        f = form.r.data
        h = sin2cos2(f)
    else:
        h = None

    return render_template("view.html", form=form, h=h)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

compute.py

```
import math

def sin2(r):
    return (math.sin(r)) ** 2

def cos2(r):
    return (math.cos(r)) ** 2

def sin2cos2(r):
    return (math.sin(r)) ** 2 + (math.cos(r)) ** 2
```

/template/view.html

```
<form method=post action="">
The sine2 of
  {{ (form.r) }}
  <input type=submit value=equals>
{% if s != None %}
{{ s }}
{% endif %}

<div>
The cossine2 of
  {{ (form.r) }}
  <input type=submit value=equals>
{% if e!= None %}
{{ e }}
{% endif %}
</div>

<div>
sin2(x)+cos2(x)
  {{ (form.r) }}
  <input type=submit value=equals>
{% if h!= None %}
{{ h }}
{% endif %}
</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you return the function ends and any code written after is not ran. In your situation you have three return statements, so that is why only sine2 is working because everything after is never ran. Try removing the first two return statements and replacing the last return with:

```
return render_template("view.html", form=form, s=s, e=e, h=h)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The others fields are showed now.
However, At the first start, it is necessary to fill both fields.
Only the equal in "The sine2 of" works all the time.

The equal in "The cossine2 of" works only in the first time when the fields are  filled.
 The submit to sin2+cos2 was removed.Now, it shows only the result.

Comment: Filling with 0 solved the first issue.

class InputForm(Form):
    r = FloatField(
        default = 0,
        validators=[validators.InputRequired()])

Comment: So everything is working correctly now or are there still things that need to be fixed?

Comment: When the click is on "The sine2 of" works all the time.
When the click is on "The cossine2 of", nothing happens.
This need to be fixed.

Comment: Try making three separate forms for each field since you have three compute buttons. This way, you can handle each forms submission individually